# In a Multi-index DataFrame, how to set new values to a subset of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

The following code is a sample DataFrame. How can I bulk assign/modify all the Temp numbers (say convert from deg c to deg f)?

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2013, 2014], [1, 2]],
                                   names=['year', 'visit'])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Bob', 'Guido', 'Sue'],['Day', 'Night'], ['HR', 'Temp']])

# mock some data
data = np.round(np.random.randn(4, 12), 1)
data[:, ::2] *= 10
data += 37

# create the DataFrame
hd = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

print(hd,'\n')
```

```
             Bob                   Guido                     Sue                  
             Day       Night         Day       Night         Day       Night      
              HR  Temp    HR  Temp    HR  Temp    HR  Temp    HR  Temp    HR  Temp
year visit                                                                        
2013 1      38.0  37.5  21.0  36.6  33.0  37.4  38.0  35.8  15.0  38.5  27.0  37.0
     2      47.0  36.5  37.0  36.3  31.0  38.8  37.0  38.4  62.0  34.9  45.0  35.6
2014 1      51.0  35.5  41.0  35.9  26.0  36.7  33.0  36.3  18.0  34.6  39.0  38.0
     2      46.0  37.6  29.0  37.3  42.0  37.0  31.0  37.0  47.0  37.3  30.0  36.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filter the columns for `Temp`, modify, and reassign the values back:

```py
 hd

             Bob                   Guido                     Sue
             Day       Night         Day       Night         Day       Night
              HR  Temp    HR  Temp    HR  Temp    HR  Temp    HR  Temp    HR  Temp
year visit
2013 1      35.0  38.2  45.0  38.1  38.0  36.7  43.0  40.0  38.0  37.5  35.0  37.8
     2      31.0  36.7  30.0  37.7  43.0  36.6  38.0  37.5  33.0  38.2  42.0  35.8
2014 1      32.0  37.7  39.0  35.0  37.0  37.7  51.0  37.5  28.0  39.6  43.0  37.8
     2      59.0  37.5  28.0  34.6  60.0  38.0  38.0  36.7  63.0  37.9  25.0  37.2

modified = hd.loc(axis=1)[:,:, 'Temp'].mul(1.8).add(32)

hd.update(modified)

hd

             Bob                       Guido                         Sue
             Day         Night           Day         Night           Day         Night
              HR    Temp    HR    Temp    HR    Temp    HR    Temp    HR    Temp    HR    Temp
year visit
2013 1      35.0  100.76  45.0  100.58  38.0   98.06  43.0  104.00  38.0   99.50  35.0  100.04
     2      31.0   98.06  30.0   99.86  43.0   97.88  38.0   99.50  33.0  100.76  42.0   96.44
2014 1      32.0   99.86  39.0   95.00  37.0   99.86  51.0   99.50  28.0  103.28  43.0  100.04
     2      59.0   99.50  28.0   94.28  60.0  100.40  38.0   98.06  63.0  100.22  25.0   98.96
```

Comment: Thanks! It works great! I have a more advanced question, similar to this one, and wonder if you can help answer. Appreciate the help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73015035/in-a-multi-index-dataframe-how-to-perform-matrix-multiplication-for-a-subset-of/73015919#73015919